# hadoop access without ssh

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-plugins

Is there a way to allow a developer to access a hadoop command line without SSH?  I would like to place some hadoop clusters in a specific environment where SSH is not permitted.  I have searched for alternatives such as a desktop client but so far have not seen anything.  I will also need to federate sign on info for developers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about `hadoop fs` and similar commands, you don't need SSH for this.

You just need to download Hadoop clients and configure the `hdfs-site.xml` file to point at a remote cluster. However, this is an administrative security hole, so setting up an edge node that does have trusted and audited SSH access is preferred.

Similarly, Hive or HBase or Spark jobs can be ran with the appropriate clients or configuration files without any SSH access, just local libraries

Answer (score 0):

You don't need SSH to use Hadoop. Also Hadoop is a combination of different stacks, which part of Hadoop are you referring to specifically? If you are talking about HDFS you can use web HDFS. If you are talking about YARN you can use API call. There are also various UI tools such as HUE you can use. Notebook apps such as Zeppelin or Jupiter can also be helpful.